# Piano no damping after transport?

Tags: piano, tuning

I recently received a 100 years old baby grand piano, which does not have any damping, that is, the dampers don't touch the strings even with no pedal being pressed and when I play a tone it just resonates forever without stopping.  When I press the right pedal the dampers go up even more so the pedal seems to be functional in principle. The original owner says it didn't have this problem in the morning before the transport.  I called the transport company and they said this is not their responsibility and I need to pay a tuner myself.  The problem is that I want to tune it after summer because if I tune it now I expect it to be out of tune again soon as it is not yet used to the different environment. Are they correct that I really need to pay a tuner myself for this problem? I never heard of this happening before.

P.S.: I contacted the transport company again and they said it is not possible to attach the pedals or lyre in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the person who re-attached the pedal lyre to the piano after it was moved did something wrong. I would suggest first removing the lyre completely, so you can get a clear view of all the parts of the mechanism.

If the dampers work correctly with the lyre off, use your common sense to figure out how the parts should fit together. Possibly the vertical rod in the lyre should have engaged in a recess in the lever in the piano, but it was actually pushing against the side of the recess and raising the dampers too high.

If the dampers still don't work correctly with the lyre off, something more serious has gone wrong - and you might as well leave the lyre off, while waiting for a piano technician. Note, you don't have to get the piano *tuned* if you only want the tech to *repair or adjust* something mechanical, like the pedals.

Warning - be careful. If it is incorrectly assembled, the pedal lyre is one of the most fragile parts of the piano - and most pianists use their feet less carefully, and more forcefully, than their fingers!

Answer (score 1):

The rod that joins the pedal to the mechanism has moved, or needs adjusting. Maybe it's just dropped out of the correct position. Look under the piano,and try to see where the rod goes. It should be a simple fix, without reference to a tuner.